# Como corretamente somar quantidade de eventos ocorridos em dado período do dia?

Tags: microsoft-excel, matemática

Tenho os seguintes dados de uma planilha como exemplo:

| visitas |
| --- |
| 17:33 |
| 17:38 |
| 17:40 |
| 16:15 |
| 16:20 |
| 16:28 |

Como posso consolidar esses dados contando quantas visitas houveram entre diferentes espaços de tempo para preencher a tabela abaixo?:

| periodo | inicio | fim | visitantes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| manhã | 6:00 | 12:00 | 0 |
| tarde | 12:00 | 18:00 | 6 |

Tentei a seguinte fórmula mas sem sucesso:

```
=CONT.NÚM(SE(E('Tabela imagem 1'!$K$2:$K$43>='Tabela imagem 2'!$D$30;'Tabela imagem 1'!$K$2:$K$43<='Tabela imagem 2'!$E$30);1;""))
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: A pergunta está clara.

Comment: Não publique dados como imagem, os dados devem ser publicados como texto. Veja como [criar tabelas em markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables) e [Não postar código, dados e mensagem de erro](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387). Modifiquei sua pergunta na intenção de reabri-la, achei interessante e útil. Caso não esteja de acordo com as modificações que fiz em sua pergunta [você a pode restaurar revertendo para uma edição anterior.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/553371/revisions) Você também pode a reeditar e fazer melhorias que achar necessárias.

Comment: Ajudaria também dizer o que saiu de errado, e a lógica usada para a tentativa. Olhando o código não dá pra saber o que é `$K$43`, `$D$30;` etc. (se forem valores fixos, a substituição atende ao [mcve], que ajuda futuros visitantes a identificarem ao menos qual foi o problema (mesmo que não saibam a solução, pois isso é o que faz com que as respostas sejam úteis para outros com problema parecido). O nome das linhas e colunas ajuda até a formatar a resposta.